# Google App Engine only deploying *some* images

Tags: python, image, web-services, google-app-engine, caching

I recently deployed a website for my dad using Google App Engine.

Oddly, some images in the gallery are found, while some return with a 404. I looked in the admin dashboard for usage rates, and it says I'm only at 17% of "Code and Static File Storage".

I have tried changing the directory and re-deploying, I have also created a second application (from this-site-1 to this-site-2), and I have waited about an hour in case it's simply the cache, but none of these seem to be the issue.

I'm brand new to Google App Engine, this is the first website I've deployed using it, so any help would be much appreciated.

**`app.yaml`**

```
application: this-site-2
version: 1
runtime: python
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

**Edit**: I updated python to 2.7 in case that was the problem, but I did by doing this:

```
application: this-site-2
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /.*
  script: main.app # a WSGI application in the main module's global scope

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

- name: django
  version: "1.2"

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yml
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.less$
```

Then I deployed, and the console said that the deployment was successful and it was updating the indexes and exited with code 0. Then I tried to go to the website and it returned with a `500 server error`. So I downgraded back to python 2.5 and the site is fine.

Comment: Would you mind showing the relevant portions of your app.yaml and your html?

Comment: Updated. The HTML code you can view via the view source, but multiple pages are affected (not just the gallery), for instance, the Product page is also missing it's images. I'm using basic `img src:...` and for some pages I use the `../path/img.png` because they're sub-pages.

Comment: Give some examples of files that are working and files that aren't working.  It could be that your regexp isn't quite matching the names of some of the files.  My first guess is that some files might have the file extensions capitalized.

Comment: Yes that's what I just now discovered. Some file names went by `jpg` where some others went by `JPG` and `jpeg`. So in my `app.yaml` file I also added `JPG` and `jpeg`. I'm deploying the website now and waiting for it to finish. It's taking a while and I'm gonna see if it works... Sure is taking a while though. Started 9 minutes ago and is still busy.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it. Changed the regexp, deployed it, images are still missing.

Comment: http://www.davidcottonwoodworks.com/app/images/Case/01.med.JPG (capitalised JPG) loads for me.

Comment: I tend to just upload everything from img, js, css specific directories and so don't have to worry about all the various regexes. e.g.  `- url: /assets/img/(.*)
  static_files: img/\1
  upload: img/(.*) `  having mixed case for filenames is a recipe for problems, you could have mixed case in the file names, in your code, in your html....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, my dad solved it;

Simply change the `jpg` images that aren't working to a `png` image (and vice versa, if it's a `png` image not working, convert it to a `jpg`)

Answer (score 3):

I think your image url handler is more complicated than it needs to be. I would suggest:

1. Put all static content (images, Javascript, CSS) in a folder called `static` or similar with subfolders for images, Javascript and CSS.
2. Use the following handler instead of your current image handler:

   ```
   handlers:
   - url: /images
     static_dir: static/images
   ```

All files in the `static/images` folder will then be accessible on the url `yourwebsite.com/images/subpath/image.jpg`.

For more inspiration, see [this `app.yaml`](https://github.com/ibagrak/algae/blob/master/gae/app.yaml).

Comment: Hmm. I tried it and it still has the same result. I updated the `app.yaml` file to the edit above.

Comment: What's weird is I know that it's handling it right in the `app.yaml` because all the stylesheets, scripts, and _some_ images are found, while _some_ image don't. It's like it's being picky which ones it likes and which ones it doesn't...

Comment: Ok, it is a weird issue for sure. Good thing you checked the images themselves and [solved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18730580/2021517).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out that it deploying images with lower case file extensions like this: `name.png`, but not ones with capital file extensions like this: `name.PNG`. Helpfully Windows hides this from you, so you can't always tell.